# Почему перед миграциями выполняется запрос?

Tags: laravel, миграция

Я запускаю миграции. Вываливается ошибка:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dhc.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users`)
```

Никаких таблиц не создалось. В первой миграции нет ссылки на таблицу users.

Подскажите - откуда волобще мог взяться запрос к юзерам? Где поискать?

Comment: SQL: select * from `users` - намекает где глянуть

Comment: Намекает? А я не понимаю :(

Comment: Возможно у вас где то подгружается получение всех пользователей. Посмотрите провайдеры и в целом весь код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорей всего вы создали create миграцию из alter миграции. И забыли поменять метод table на create. Ищите миграцию с кодом table('users').